# Bitap algorithm for Fuzzy search example

Tags: string-matching, fuzzy-search, nfa

I was looking at this [work](https://file:///C:/Users/filip/Downloads/TR_DCC-1999-005.pdf) page 31. It is talking about the Wu and Manber 1992 updated Bitap algorithm for Fuzzy search with Non-deterministic Automata. To be more precise this formula:
[image]
[image]

Let's also look at this NFA graph which is used for finding words that are of distance 2 by Levenstein away from the word **"survey"**:
[image]
As per my understanding the formula is used for each state. NFA graph tells us we approve **2 errors**, which means we should calculate $R_{0}$, $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$.

However how would we calculate this example:

```
Text = "surprise"

Pattern = "rise"

Then the Bitmask is: 

B["r"] = 1000

B["i"] = 0100

B["s"] = 0010

B["e"] = 0010

B[*] = 0000 where * stands for any other character
```

Okey for **0 errors** we will get 0001 on the last letter as we only use $R'_{0}$. But anything that contains more than **0 errors** gets me confused. Does the **i** value stands for index in text or for how many errors we approve.

I also found this Russian article which states that:
[image]

**k** is number of errors, **j** is character index and **$s_{x}$** is Bitmask. However the previous article stated that **i** are states of the NFA.
Can you please explain how would the formula work for **1 error** or **2**, it is so confusing.

Comment: The variable "k" is definitely the number of errors. The variables "i" and "j" are the same here. For the case of fuzzy matching, wikipedia says "Array R_i holds a representation of the prefixes of pattern that match any suffix of the current string with i or fewer errors". There are "k" distinct arrays.

( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitap_algorithm - there are links to other sources. )

Good luck!

Comment: Also, you accidentally posted a link to a local file! Obviously, that won't open for anyone but you : )